# Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server

Why is this piece of code not displaying the PrimarySmtpAddress?

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | where{$_.TotalItemSize -ge 1000MB} | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress,TotalItemSize | Export-CSV mailboxsize.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you piped the results of Get-Mailbox into Get-MailboxStatistics.

Get-Mailbox returns Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox objects, which contain the PrimarySmtpAddress property. But once you pipe those objects into another cmdlet, Get-MailboxStatistics in this case, the rest of the pipeline contains the results of that cmdlet. So after Get-MailboxStatistics runs, the pipeline contains Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Mapi.MailboxStatistics objects instead -- these objects do NOT have the PrimarySmtpAddress property. You'd need to store the PrimarySmtpAddress in a variable before passing the objects into the pipeline; something like this:

```
foreach ($mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {
    $properties = @{
        PrimarySmtpAddress = $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress
        TotalItemSize = $mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize
    }
    New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
} | where{$_.TotalItemSize -ge 1000MB} | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending
```

Comment: I get an error on the pipe before the last where statement.  The exact error is: An empty pipe element is not allowed. @jbsmith

Comment: I think you are on the right track, @jbsmith, but as-is this does not work.

Comment: Gah - I wrote the code without testing it. In testing, I'm running into an issue with implicit remoting (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156368/exchange-2010-totalitemsize-value-tobytes-always-empty).

You can get around the "empty pipe" error by adding an extra set of  {} braces, starting at the very beginning (before 'foreach') and ending before ' | where'.

You will also probably want to change the TotalItemSize definition to TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB(), and then remove the 'MB' from the where clause. See the linked question for more detail on that.