# Filtering Out Lines Not Containing Defined Values PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, filtering

I have a list of users and emails that I am trying to filter. I want to remove all emails that do not match what a define. For example, I only want 'user@example.com' listed and 'user@other.com' or 'user@something.com' not listed.

This is my script:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 50 | Select-Object DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, Alias | Sort-Object DisplayName | Out-GridView
```

As you can see, there are multiple columns (DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, and Alias). I want to target 'PrimarySmtpAddress' and filter from that column.

Comment: This is not unique to what you are doing, as it is just object value/string parsing. This is why the 'Where-Object' cmdlet comes into play or simple RegEx string matching. This is a very common thing and has been asked on SO several times. Use the SO search box to find them, as well as many examples all over the web.

Comment: You can use the `-Filter` provided by `Get-Mailbox`. `Get-Mailbox -Filter "PrimarySmtpAddress -Like '*other.com' -or PrimarySmtpAddress -Like '*example.com'"`

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment.

> For example: [Lots of examples for you to work from.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Get-Mailbox%20-ResultSize%20get%20PrimarySmtpAddress%27&t=h_&ia=web)
>
> [Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143835/select-object-primarysmtpaddress)
>
> Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress

```
foreach ($mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {
    $properties = @{
        PrimarySmtpAddress = $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress
        TotalItemSize = $mailbox | 
                        Get-MailboxStatistics | 
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize
    }
    New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
} | 
where{$_.TotalItemSize -ge 1000MB} | 
Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending
```

> PowerShell script to export display name and primary smtp address of
> all users
>
> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/powershell-script-to-export-display-name-and-primary-smtp/m-p/730888

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress,EmailAddresses,EmailAddresses | 
Export-CSV C:\Temp\"Exchange Online recipients.CSV" –NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

You can then use Where-Object or matching or comparison operators as needed.